# Node.js mysql Syntax Error in Merge Statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an sql query that is Constructed as follows:

```
tmpQUERY = "INSERT INTO vertix_users (user_name, user_email, user_pass) " +
    "VALUES (" + mysql.escape(userName) +
    ", " + mysql.escape(userEmail) + 
    ", " + mysql.escape(userPass) + ")";

tmpQUERY = "MERGE vertix_users WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS oldData " +
    "USING (VALUES (@user_name, @user_email)) AS newData (" + mysql.escape(userName) + ", " + mysql.escape(userEmail) + ") " +
    "ON newData.user_name = oldData.user_name AND newData.user_email = oldData.user_email " +
    "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN " + tmpQUERY;
```

When I execute the code, I get the following log:

```
MERGE vertix_users WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS oldData USING (VALUES (@user_name, @user_email)) AS newData ('asfasfsaff vvv', 'asfasfasfasf') ON newData.user_name = oldData.user_name AND newData.user_email = oldData.user_email WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT INTO vertix_users (user_name, user_email, user_pass) VALUES ('asfasfsaff vvv', 'asfasfasfasf', 'saqqq')
```

And a sql syntax error that reads:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MERGE vertix_users WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS oldData USING (VALUES (@user_name, @user_e' at line 1]
```

A simple insert statement without the merge works fine, but as soon as I add the second portion of that code, it creates that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MERGE` is not supported by `MySQL`, The equivalent for that is

**[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**

Comment: Wont that cause a race condition? The reason I went with the merge solution is to avoid that.

Comment: I doubt it causes any race condition, because that's a single MySQL command, aka atomic operation. You don't have the option to use MERGE on MySQL.

Comment: I looked at the duplicate key update. Im not sure how to only do the insert if there is no duplicate. I am trying to prevent the insertion of users with the same name.

Comment: then add a UNIQUE index on the column that stores the value you want to be unique (the name for example)